# Access join table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an Rail 5 app and in this app I got several models.
Survey, Question and SurveyQuestion (join table).

**Survey**

```
has_many :survey_questions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :questions, :through => :survey_questions
```

**Question**

```
has_many :question_surveys
has_many :surveys, :through => :question_surveys
```

**SurveyQuestion**

```
belongs_to :survey
belongs_to :question
```

The SurveyQuestion object got an attribute called *sorting*. I want to be able to access this attribute when getting the question objects but I only get the questions objects back (which is good) but I need this attribute from the join table too (sorting):

```
@survey.questions
```

How can I access the join table attribute?
Alternatively I want to sort the @survey.questions by the join table attribute (sorting).

Do I have to fetch question join table objects and then build a new array of questions in Survey method?

```
def ordered_question
    questions = []
    items = self.survey_questions.joins(:question).order("sorting desc")
    items.each do |item|
        questions << item.question
    end
    questions
end
```

Comment: Try https://pastebin.com/KA9aJDaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not sort the collection array?

```
@survey.survey_questions.sort_by{ |sq| -sq.sort }.map{ |sq| sq.question }
```

Check if you have e typo: `has_many :question_surveys`